# Arithmetic Operation in Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

How can I do some arithmetic operation in thymeleaf. I have tested so many ways. But unable to get the output. If U know, Please let me know.

Here is my code:

```
/*Dummy Content */ 
<p class="quan-inc-dec">
    <input type="hidden" name="productId" th:value="*{product.id}" class="productId"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="orderItemId" th:value="*{id}" class="orderItemId"/>
    <input type="button" name="minus" class="minus" value="-" autocomplete="off"/>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="result" autocomplete="off" th:value="*{quantity}"/>
    <input type="button" name="plus" class="plus" autocomplete="off" value="+"/>
</p>
/*Dummy Content End*/
<span th:text="${${obj.baseRetailPrice}*${obj.aa}}"><!-- I need the Result Here --></span>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this:

```
<div th:with="result=${obj.baseRetailPrice * obj.aa}">
  <span th:text="${result}"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this without the div as well.

Comment: @user3344977, could you explain how?

Comment: @Marvo you can look at `th:block`