# How to FormatDecimal in Tyhmeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I m trying to convert a (string) value from kilometers to miles directly in my template :

```
<td th:with="trip_distance_in_miles=${trip_distance * 0.621371}">
    <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(trip_distance_in_miles, 3, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"> </span> mi
</td>
```

**But it fails. Any ideas what's wrong?**

---

I know this works:

```
        <td >
            <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(trip_distance, 3, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"> </span> mi
        </td>
```

PS: I am aware of the SO post of [Arithmetic Operation in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775217/arithmetic-operation-in-thymeleaf)
But I am not sure about the use of literal values such as '0.62' and the format decimal function in conjunction with a local variable. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic Operation in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775217/arithmetic-operation-in-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally this worked :

```
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" th:with="trip_distance_in_miles=(${trip_distance} * 0.621371)">

    <tr class="item" >
        <td>
            Distance Driven
        </td>
        <td >
            <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(trip_distance_in_miles, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}"> </span> mi
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did extra brackets at ${trip_distance * 0.621371} solve the problem?

Comment: that and adding the th:with in the <table > tag instead of the <td>