# Spring Thymeleaf multiply two variables in function

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have some field that formatted throw Spring Formatter class. I use expression `th:text="${{variable}}"` for formatting this variable on view, but I need to multiply this variable on variable from controller. So I tried something like this `th:text="${{variable * controllerVar}}"` or this `th:text="${{variable}} * ${controllerVar}"`. But this doesn't work. Also I tried to create variable like this `th:with="var=${{variable}}"` and `th:text="${var * controllerVar}"` but it doesn't work too... And after that I need put this to function something like that `th:text="#numbers.formatCurrency(here put result)"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic Operation in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775217/arithmetic-operation-in-thymeleaf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works. You just need to change the variables `variable` and `controllerVar` with your current variables.

```
<th:block th:with="variable = 10, controllerVar = 12, var = ${variable * controllerVar}">
    <p th:text="${var}"></p>
</th:block>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using it like this?

```
th:with="var=${variable * controllerVar}"
```

and

```
th:text="${var}"
```