# Is it possible to use thymeleaf variables to sum them in JS?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Here is the form I have ( many dishes where each has an input number ( quantity of dishes to order ).

The problem is that I would like to show the price of an order before the order is done, for this I need to sum somehow input of the `${dish.price}`, but how can this be done?

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/menu}" th:object="${order}" method="post">

    <div th:each="dish : ${dishList}">
                    <div>
                        <h4 th:inline="text">[[${dish.name}]]<span class="price" th:text="${dish.price}">45</span></h4>
                        <p th:text="${dish.category}">DRINKS</p>
                        <p th:text="${dish.description}">
                            Aperiam tempore sit,perferendis numquam repudiandae porro
                            voluptate dicta saepe facilis.
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
                            <input
                                    th:value="0"
                                    th:name="${'dishIdQuantityMap[' + dish.id + ']'}"
                                    type="number"
                                    min="0"
                                    max="100"
                                    step="1"
                            />
                            <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Confirm order</button>

</form>
```

JS ( Just inputs +1 to `input type"number"` when the button is clicked )

```
    function stepperDecrement(btn){
    const inputEl = btn.nextElementSibling;
    const calcStep =inputEl.step * -1;
    const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
    if(newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max){
        inputEl.value = newValue;
    }
}
function stepperIncrement(btn){
    const inputEl = btn.previousElementSibling;
    const calcStep = inputEl.step * 1;
    const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
    if(newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max){
        inputEl.value = newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course yes, it is possible.

To get server data inside your thymeleaf templates, you can proceed various ways, and it depends on the context where you need that data.

Inside Javascript, (CSP "script-src 'unsafe-inline' ..." or `<script th:inline="javascript" nonce="" ...>` are required because writing JS inline is a bad way regarding all XSS caveats. Thanks OWASP), you can try to write : `let productCategory = /*[[${productCategory}]]*/ '';`

Inside Javascript with ES6+ modules (with webpack or any other solution), you can check an endpoint of your webapp (using Promise feature with polyfill) which will load data inside a form input element. And make your operations as usual. Have fun.

Comment: I need to have order total price, for this to sum all `${dish.price}` * `input value`. How can this be done? I've spend a lot of time on this and would appreciate it **so much** if you could help me.

Comment: Hello Mark, you can look at the official thymeleaf documentation here for arithmetic operations : https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#arithmetic-operations or you can look inside stackoverflow.com with search tool : you will find post like this one exactly for what you need : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805059/390462. Have a dood day !

Comment: The fast answer is to put operation inside the brackets ;) `${dish.price * inputValue}` but the documentation is clearer than that, and you'll find many use cases for daily work.

Comment: and for operands that did not come from java side but from your form, the simplest way - and certainly the best to do it - is to store any java inputs inside javascript variables as I have answered first, then do any javascript calculations to get the results you need.